# Report doesn't finish loading due to chart

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

we have a loading-issue with some reports. We have different reports embedded in our software, which runs on the iPad: as soon as there is a chart in the rdl, the report is stuck and doesn't finish loading.

We recently migrated the affected system to another server, changed the end-user-device from Windows to iPad. There were no changes made on the Report Server or to the reports. Also, all the reports without a chart load without any problem.

If I open a report that includes a chart, I can see all the data in the first place - but no chart! And the report seems to never stop loading, I've waited more than an hour.

The report and the sql procedure behind it works perfectly fine on the server itself and every other client except for the iPad. I can export/save the report on the iPad while it's loading and I'm able to successfully open that PDF-file. That saved file has all the informations in it, even the charts that don't seem to load.

I checked the ExecutionLog, every request I did finished successfully in 2 seconds. I also restarted the reporting server, but that didn't lead to success. I also didn't find anything unusual with the sql profiler.

My next step would be to look at the whole situation with fiddler. But before I do that, I thought I'd ask you guys! Maybe you've encountered this problem before and can help me out.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the browser/renderer rather than the report. I suspect if you open the report URL on a Windows client using Chrome or Edge it will work. I've had something similar on Windows clients (showing "loading" forever) but that was using the default web portal and clearing the browser cache and restarting the browser always fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried clearing the cache and stuff, but it didn't help. However, I looked at the traffic via Fiddler and I found a workaround. The url access to the reports contained rs:toolbar=false - as soon as I tried calling the report via the url without the toolbar=false and it worked! The charts are loading now. But I can't seem to figure out the reason why the charts don't load if the toolbar is activated.